# ImportError: No module named whoosh2

Tags: django, search

I did pip install whoosh, why am I getting this error?
my code can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520966/haystack-exceptions-searchbackenderror-no-fields-were-found-in-installation-st

Comment: The question given in the link has a different error and your current question here has a different error!?

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro I fixed that one, but now I get this error. Code is still the same

Comment: Can you post the error log? Maybe you are using an incorrect virtualenv.

Comment: the error dissapeared as I've removed whoosh folder I copied from a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-n6_m66TmA,,,,when I configure whoosh am I suppose to add some folder named whoosh with some docu

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the `ImportError: No module named whoosh2` error occurs when accessing an old whoosh index with updated libraries.  The error went away after regenerating the whoosh index.